# How to compile strings that have html elements to display on the web

Tags: php, html, laravel, compilation

I have a string from the database, which has the html tag inside it. everything is the result of the process of CKEditor.

I tried several ways but it didn't work

```
`$data_from_db = <strong> this is title </strong>`
```

what I hope is the   **this is title**  are printed in bold on the web. but what appears is still `<strong> this is title </strong>`

Comment: try using single quotes between the string, and then just echo the variable.

Comment: Thank you for help. This successfully displays the results. previously I used {{$ variable}} in the blade.php file, and it didn't work. after I print using normal php echo it works

Comment: To make it work on a blade file using Laravel just follow Vrian7 answer below.

Comment: you are right party ring, and sorry for that. so do I have to delete my posts? I'm a new user of stackoverflow so I don't really understand..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want render HTML use

`{!! $yourvar !!}`

into your .blade file

Comment: Thank before. the code is functioning as it should, but there is something strange about the output. there is a sign `{` at the beginning and at the end

Comment: Please show your code. Don't you added doble {{! !!}} like this?, its just one { and two !

Comment: You're right, apparently I entered the wrong code. I write `{{!! $ variable !!}}`

thank you very much for the answer. very helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can use html_entity_decode for this

From php.net

> html_entity_decode() is the opposite of htmlentities() in that it converts HTML entities in the string to their corresponding characters.

source:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: solved from the comment above. thanks for your help :)